# How to pass variables into next function without using global

Tags: python

I'm currently looking how I can take the variables that I've saved into the next function. To illustrate what I mean, I'm getting the latest version number online as such:

```
try:
     webversion = urllib2.urlopen(
         "http://www." + server + "/version").read().rstrip()
     if webversion > version:
          update_files()
     elif version >= webversion:
          print "[SYSTEM] You have the latest version: v." + version
```

In the `update_files()` function, I would very much like to take the variable I've gained (`webversion` and possibly `version`) over to the next function.

I'm thinking of setting this variable as global:

```
try:
     global webversion
     webversion = urllib2.urlopen(
         "http://www." + server + "/version").read().rstrip()
     if webversion > version:
          update_files()
     elif version >= webversion:
          print "[SYSTEM] You have the latest version: v." + version
```

Is there a better way/smarter to do this?

Comment: Why don't you simply change your function to accept version number as an argument?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just pass arguments to the function:

function definition:

```
def update_files(webversion, version):
    # ... function execution
```

and code:

```
try:
     # global webversion we don't need it
     webversion = urllib2.urlopen("http://www." + server + "/version").read().rstrip()
     if webversion > version:
          update_files(webversion, version)
     elif version >= webversion:
          print "[SYSTEM] You have the latest version: v." + version
#And be careful to add except, with try!
except:
    print("Error!")
```

Comment: You might remove the `global webversion` as well

Comment: and we don't need to use global.

Comment: Thank you @Vincent, that does seem logical. When I change the code it gives me an error though: TypeError: update_files() takes exactly 2 arguments (0 given). I have no experience with this, so how can I give update_files function those two arguments?

Comment: it is `update_files(webversion, version)` (you give two args) instead of `update_files()` (you give 0 args)

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you pass variables from one function to the other, provided that they are both in the same file:

```
def my_second_function(my_var):
    print(my_var)


def my_first_function(var_1, var_2):
    my_second_function(var_1):

    # do whatever you want here.
    return True
```

`my_var` will have the same value as `var_1` if called from `my_first_function` like so:

```
my_first_function(6,2)
```

Note that `my_second_function` must be defined before `my_first_function` if the script is run individually and not imported elsewhere. Alternatively, you can run your programme using:

```
if __name__ == '__main__': 
    my_second_function(6, 2)
```

### Your case:

In you case, we can define it as:

```
def update_files(web_ver, ver):
    # You can do whatever you want with these, including sending them elsewhere.

    return True  # or whatever


try:
     webversion = urllib2.urlopen("http://www." + server + "/version").read().rstrip()

     if webversion > version:
         update_files(webversion, version)

     else:
         print("[SYSTEM] You have the latest version: v." + version)

 except:
     print("Error!")

 update_files(webversion, version)
```

You can also `return web_ver, ver`, or `return another_func(web_ver, ver)`.